# Detecting button clicks within a for loop in an Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm having a little bit of trouble. There are 12 buttons, and 10 questions in my android app. If I ran a for loop for all of the questions is there a way that I can check if a button is pushed and if it's the answer to the current question? Then it would move on to the next question, and do the same until the loop ended. I don't know exactly how to word it, but I hope you can figure out what I mean.

Comment: Are 12buttons there for each question?

Comment: Yes. Twelve for each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to create 10 activities (or 1 activity that takes in the question as an Extra).

The user would then step through the activities as they answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

The process is event driven. You push a button, go to next question.
So you can't use a loop. Instead, use a state variable that tells you in which question you are. Each time you press a button you check for correctness of the question corresponding to your state variable.

If the answer is correct, update the state variable to the next question.
You can also apply graphics in these events, that mark a question as done.

Answer (score 1):

I would `setOnClickListener`'s only for the first `Button` and after confirming that the answer to the question is right, I would let him go to the next question, here is how you do it..

Firstly store your answers in some Collection like a String Array or a List, then compare to see that the `Button` clicked by the user is the right answer or not..

```
yourFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click like
             String str = yourFirstButton.getText();
           //if answer is correct then let him go to next question..
             if(str == StringArray[5]){ //here StringArray[5] refers to correct answer 
             // go to next question here
             }
             else{
            //stay on the same question or let him try again...
             }
         });
```